# Most efficient way to extract data from string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, split, substring

There are so many ways to extract data from a string whether it be `substring, split, etc`. This is an open ended question and may be too open ended, but is there a "right" way to do this? For example I have a URL `http://myServer:8000/courses/courseName/courseID` what is the right way to extract out `courseID` in this instance?

This is an example of what I have done:

```
const test2 = test.split('/courses/').slice(1).toString();
const test3 = test2.substring(0, test2.lastIndexOf('/'))
console.log(test3)
```

Comment: If it's a url search parameter, there's an *proper* way to get it using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). But if it's a part of url path, you may get the pathname using `new URL('your url').pathname` first and then you're free to use anything as long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code can help you get the last part of the URL in a single line using Javascript. This will work if the CourseID is always the last element of the URL. I am not sure how fast is it but definitely, it is elegant

```
url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```